# Changing the number of significant digits for a string format with %g

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm building an app that allows the user to perform some calculations except the calculations result in numbers with lots of decimal digits. It's fine for me to see that kind of precision but I want to let the users be able to choose how many significant digits they want shown. I'm creating a result string using a double and using the %g format shown here:

`NSString *resultString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%.14g", result];`

I have created a stepper that the users can interact with and storing the number they have chosen in another double. My question is, how can insert that double where the `14` is to change the number of significant digits? Or is this even possible? Please comment if you need clarification.

Comment: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/printf.html -- See in particular the discussion about the meaning of `*`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any field width or precision in a format can be replaced by an `*` to indicate a dynamic value which is supplied by an `int` argument.

For example:

```
double d = 1.0/7;
for(int i = 4; i < 12; i++)
   NSLog(@"%.*g", i, d);
```

Outputs:

```
0.1429
0.14286
0.142857
0.1428571
0.14285714
0.142857143
0.1428571429
0.14285714286
```

Comment: Thanks CRD this really helps! I was unaware of the *. Thanks.

Comment: How did I not know about this?  Delightful bit of info, thanks :-)